# Entry not saving when Redactor bold

Tags: entry, redactor, saveentry, saving, onsaveentry

I'm having a weird issue with the Rich Text Editor (Redactor -> simple.json, only "bold" and "italic") on newly added fields and only ONE (that i know of) older field.
Every time i add a "bold" format and then save the entry, it goes back to its previous state and never actually saves it.

If there is a bold word in that block and i try to add / modify other blocks, nothing saves either.

If i don't use "bold" in THAT specific field or newly created ones, it all works perfectly. Even the "italic" option works. If i use "bold" in an other older field, it works perfectly.

It used to work like a charm, no updates has been done since (i did it afterwards to try and solve it: nothing changed).

No trace about that in the craft logs.

Any idea what's the problem? Or how to debug further?

PS: That one is on Craft 2.7.2!

Comment: Any chance you've got something like mod_security or Suhosin installed on your server?

Comment: @BradBell Right, i disabled mod_security on that specific dev, but is there a more stable solution, where i can keep mod_security in production mode?

Comment: You'd need to find the specific mod_security rule that's tripping up the request and disable it or modify it so it allows that POST data through.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was a [ModSecurity](https://www.modsecurity.org/) tripping up the contents of the particular Redactor field in the POST request.

The nuclear option for a fix is to disable ModSecurity.  The more nuanced fix is to find the particular rule that is tripping up the request and either disable it or to modify it so it allows that content through.